# If list contains 4 of the given gameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to find how I can check if 4 of the given gameObjects are in a list.
So I have a list with gameObjects. Sometimes a gameObject gets out of the list, sometimes it gets in. I want to check if 4 of the same colors are in a list. In this case, "childTiles" is the list. 
I tried it by doing this:

```
void Update()
{
    foreach (GameObject tile in ChildTiles) 
    {
        if (tile.gameObject.name == "tileGreen1" && tile.gameObject.name == "tileGreen2" && tile.gameObject.name == "tileGreen3" && tile.gameObject.name == "tileGreen4") 
        {
            gameManager.finalGreenComplete = true;
            Debug.Log (gameManager.finalGreenComplete);
        }
    }
}
```

This returns nothing. It does work if I check only 1 object. I also can't use `ChildTiles.Contains()` I think, because that is only possible with 1 gameObject if I'm right. So how do I check this with multiple gameObjects?

EDIT: A bit more information.

I have 4 different colors, each color has 4 tiles. Everytime the player clicks a button, the parent will rotate with the tiles as child. The childs are automatically child of a specific parent. The parents are the colliders (in the image below the white gameobjects are the colliders. They normally have no sprite renderer) which is behind the button that is pressed. The grey circles are the buttons.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/38fcf90e6bebe43763f5d358dd19f093.png]

The following script is attached to all the white colliders. The public void Squareclicked is attached to each button, but it is in the same script.

```
public List<GameObject> ChildTiles = new List<GameObject>();

public void SquareClicked()
{
    if (parentPositions.canTurn == true && gameManager.turns > 0f)
        {
        gameManager.turns -= 1;
        gameManager.turnsText.text = "Turns: " + gameManager.turns;
        foreach(GameObject go in ParentPositions)
        {
            parentPositions = go.GetComponent<TileController> ();
            parentPositions.canTurn = false;
        }

        foreach(GameObject tile in ChildTiles)
        {
            tile.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        }
        StartCoroutine(Rotate()); //this is where you do the rotation of the parent object.

        if (gameManager.turns == 0f) 
        {
            gameManager.turnsText.text = "No turns left";
        }
    }
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Tile") 
    {
        ChildTiles.Add (col.gameObject);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Tile") 
    {
        ChildTiles.Remove (col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Only the top-left, the top-right, the bottom-left and the bottom-right colliders are needed to check wheter is has four of the same color in it's list. I can either make a new script and attach that to those colliders (gameObjects) or I can make it so that the script only works for those.

Comment: I would use enums to record the colour rather than names. Then you could just check if ChildTiles.Count(a=>a.Colour==Colour.Green)

Answer (score 0):

The conditional will certainly never be true, since for a given `tile`, `tile.gameObject.name` has some given string value, and you are checking that every tile has each of the four names.

If I understand the question correctly, you want to check that within `ChildTiles`, there is some `GameObject` whose `.gameObject.name` is `"tileGreen1"`, one that is `"tileGreen2"`, and so on. If so, and if performance is not critical, you could check write the condition as follows:

```
var names = ChildTiles.Select(tile => tile.gameObject.name);
var shouldBeContained = new List<string> { "tileGreen1", "tileGreen2", "tileGreen3", "tileGreen4" };
bool condition = shouldBeContained.All(names.Contains);
```

Comment: That will iterate through the list 5 times. Is there a way to reduce that?

Comment: @Yair Halberstadt: It will only do so worst case: if `"tileGreen1"` is not in `names`, `All` will short-circuit and not check for the rest. That being said, if the condition is actually true, one iteration will of course suffice, but in that iteration you will still have to check almost every element four times worst case, so the worst case scenarios are probably comparable. So, performance-wise, the optimal solution depends a bit on what one can expect `names` to look like.

Comment: I also have the colors blue, red and yellow. (tileRed1, tileBlue3....) Now if I use this code and if the green tiles are together in a list, then the other colors also turn true. I did change the variables for each color.

Comment: @ J.K Harthoon. Using names to store the colour is the completely wrong way to go about this. You should use an enum in each GameObject to store each colour. You will find your program easier to code, and it will run faster too.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I've never used enums. I just watched a tutorial but how would it look in this case? Could you make a new answer?

Comment: @J.K Harthoon. I don't have time right now, but may have later today. However I will need you to post the code containing the gameobject class.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt I edited my question, is this clear enough?

Comment: Hopefully. I will try later

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn. Done

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your request to explain how to use enums for colors here:
I don't have unity, so I can't guarantee this will work, but anyway.

First, define your enum:

```
public enum Color
{
    Black,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Yellow,
    ///...
}
```

Next inherit a Tile object from GameObject (or whatever you want to use as a base class) and add a color property to it. Use these instead of GameObject as the Type of the ChildTiles.

```
public class Tile : GameObject
{
    public Color Color { get; private set; }
    public Tile(Color color) :base()
    {
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

Then your Update function should look something like this:

```
void Update()
{
        if (ChildTiles.Count(a => a.Color == Color.Green)>=4)
        {
            gameManager.finalGreenComplete = true;
            Debug.Log(gameManager.finalGreenComplete);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I can't really figure out where to put what. Do I place the enum code into the code from my original question, attached to the colliders? Where do I put the other codes?

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn. Enum code and public class tile code all go in their own file (C# style is one file per class). Then change `public List<GameObject> ChildTiles = new List<GameObject>();` to `public List<Tile> ChildTiles = new List<Tile>();` and the Update function is just a replacement for your original update function.

Comment: You'll also have to replace some of the other mentions of `GameObject` with `Tile`. I'll leave you to work that out.

Comment: If I put the code of the second box into a script, it returns this error: Assets/Scripts/TileColor.cs(5,14): error CS0509: `Tile': cannot derive from sealed type UnityEngine.GameObject'`

Comment: Ah. I was worried about that. I'm afraid I don't know enough about unity to know how to create a custom object. You may have to write the class yourself, or find an object that already has a color property. Maybe go searching around on the internet...Sorry.

Comment: No idea how to do that. Someone an idea?

Comment: no point asking in an old question. Look around on the internet, then if you can't find an answer, ask a new question.

Comment: I tried to look around, but I don't really know where im looking for, if you know what I mean

Comment: Yep. Neither do I i'm afraid, as I just haven't used Unity before. Really sorry about it.